# How do I get a workflow to pause until a specific day of the month?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I'm using sharepoint 2007 and my requirement is to have an email sent to a user should it reach a certain date of the month and the user hasn't updated a list item.

So the way it currently works is that a user submits a form and I have a workflow which creates a document which the users manager needs to fill out by the end of the month. I am creating a workflow which will check a list item to see if it's updated and if not I want it to send an email. My issue is timing; the form can be submitted at any time of the month, however they will be reviewed and cleared on a monthly basis. I want my workflow to check the list item 5 days before the end of the month (month on month) and send a reminder mail if not completed but I can't figure out how to identify the end of the month in a variable to create a workflow step.

Eg. If the user submitted the form on 2nd of April, I want to start a workflow to check for completion on 26th of April. If they submit it on 10th of May, I want my workflow to check for completed on the 27th of May etc. Always 5 days before the end of the month it was submitted during.

Am I missing something very easy? Everything that I search is based on date calculations, ie. +30 days but in my scenario it's dependent on a recurring monthly date, not a specific amount of time.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use (timer) job which would run (every day) only on specific date (5 days before month ends) check for running workflows in specific list/library/site. If any WFis running -> get WF item and send email to approver.

Comment: Hi Luccio, thanks for your answer. The problem I'm having though is how to identify the end of the month? Is there a formula or something that I could use that would output the last date of the current month?

Comment: Can't you just run job every day and as the first thing check the date? I use this approach sometimes in SP2010 and Timer jobs.

Comment: I can run a job every day but how will the job know what's the right date as it will change each month. I need it to check lastdayofmonth and then subtract 5. I just don't know how to identify lastdayofmonth

Comment: var date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1); date = date.AddMonths(1); var lastDateOfTheMonth = date.AddDays(-1); Or even easier => DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

Comment: I'm stuck as to where to put that code? It doesn't work within a workflow does it?

Comment: You should implement separate job

Comment: Is there anything I can do to achieve what I want to do by creating a workflow within SPD2007?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: maybe a calculated column that is hidden on the list. you can then use the column in SPD to check the date.

Comment: How would you use calculated column? It is calculated only when displayed to user.